# jquery 1.9 .html() on div not working in Chrome ? Neither does innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm using this code :

```
function updateList(searchStr){
    $.ajax(getSearchURL(true) + searchStr).done(function(data) {
        $("#div_list").html($(data).find("#div_list").html());
    });
};
```

to update my div #div_list with new data.

When I'm doing that in FF, it works flawlessly. However, in chrome, it fails with the following message in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

I divided the code in 2, like so :

```
function updateList(searchStr){
    $.ajax(getSearchURL(true) + searchStr).done(function(data) {
        var test = $(data).find("#div_list").html();
        $("#div_list").html(test);
    });
};
```

Chrome tells me the var test line is the one at fault.

After playing around a bit, I discovered that

```
$(data).find("#div_list")
```

Is indeed defined, as an alert on this will give [object Object]

So I said, hell, i'll just use normal non-jquery methods then, and tried:

```
function updateList(searchStr){
    $.ajax(getSearchURL(true) + searchStr).done(function(data) {
        $("#div_list").html($(data).find("#div_list")[0].innerHTML);
    });
};
```

This also failed, with the same TypeError.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT : A sample answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <div version="2.0" id="div_list">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require('dijit.TitlePane');
    </script>
    <div id="XXX">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>//Some rows
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>More rows with data
            </tr>
            <tr class="footer">
                <td colspan="7"><span class="new"><a href="/items?form"><img title="Create new Item"
                            src="/resources/images/add.png" alt="Create new Item" /></a></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

EDIT2: Using console.log for $(data).find("#div_list") gives

```
[div, prevObject: st.fn.st.init[1], context: document, selector: "#div_list", jquery: "1.9.0", constructor: function…]
```

Also, changing the datatype to "html" does nothing.

Comment: [object Object] doesn't mean an element has been selected. Most likely your html is invalid or not in a form that can be understood by .html consistently.

Comment: Check $(data).find("#div_list").length

Comment: What exactly is returned by your server?  In other words, what does "data" look like?

Comment: Did you try using `filter` ..  `$(data).find("#div_list").length` May be the node is at the same level of data object

Comment: Instead of using alert() to debug, try using console.log().

Comment: Also it is a better idea to set the `dataType:'html'` attribute.. If you are expecting the data to be in that format

Comment: You could try the shorthand way to do this: `$('#div_list').load(getSearchURL(true) + searchStr + ' #div_list');`

Comment: i suspect your ajax response is being parsed as XML, in which case `innerHTML` won't exist.  `console.log` should tell you the types of the DOM objects; if they don't start with `HTML`, they aren't HTML elements.

Comment: '$(data).find("#div_list").length' gives me 1 (which is what I expect)

Comment: Also, I edited in a sample answer from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured a simple way of doing what I wanted.

I turns out that using the $.load() method of jquery parses everything as HTML. That way, even if InnerHTML is not defined for XML in Chrome (which is I think the reason why the code wasn't working in chrome), it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception but in my case i were using the xml parse from jquery and what i wanted is to get the String from the parse to update the file/string.

```
$(xmlParsed).find(selector).text(value);
$root = $(xmlParsed).find('root');
```

where the exception appear in:

```
$root.html()
```

The way it works is:

```
xmlFile = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString($root.context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the class selector into ID selector works for me. Don't know the reason.

Ex.

```
<div class="abc"></div> to <div id="abc"></div>
```